# Download a zip file and unzip to internal storage Android Xamarin cross platform app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there any way to download and unzip a file from a remote server using Xamarin cross platform application.
I use the PC:Storage librray to interact with Files and folders

```
IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
        IFolder folder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("MyAppRoot\\F1",CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        IFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("firstfile.txt",
            CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        await file.WriteAllTextAsync("my content");
```

This is the way i created a folder F1 inside app root folder  and creates a files firstfile.txt and write some comtent to it. But  how can i do the same with a zip file ?
Download the zip file , unzip contents to folder .

Also how can i see the folders / files created while running the application ? Is any IsoStoreSpy kind of tools available for Xamarin android emulator ?

Comment: did you figure it out?

Comment: I have one answer of your question, If you want to see data of emulator, you can see using using Android Device Monitor (DDMS), you will find it in extreme left of Android Device Logging icon in visual studio 2015, keep in mind it will work only when your application is running.

Answer (score 0):

step one, get the file:

Xamarin helps [Downloading the file](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/networking/download_progress/)

Here's their download task in case that link moves/dies:

```
public static async Task<int> CreateDownloadTask(string urlToDownload, IProgress<DownloadBytesProgress> progessReporter)
{
int receivedBytes = 0;
int totalBytes = 0;
WebClient client = new WebClient();

using (var stream = await client.OpenReadTaskAsync(urlToDownload))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    totalBytes = Int32.Parse(client.ResponseHeaders[HttpResponseHeader.ContentLength]);

    for (;;)
    {
        int bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        if (bytesRead == 0)
        {
            await Task.Yield();
            break;
        }

        receivedBytes += bytesRead;
        if (progessReporter != null)
        {
            DownloadBytesProgress args = new DownloadBytesProgress(urlToDownload, receivedBytes, totalBytes);
            progessReporter.Report(args);
        }
    }
}
return receivedBytes;
}
```

you'll want to write that data thats being downloaded, so add to their method a file handler and do something like

```
await zipFile.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
```

then there's the unzipping, I know I've downloaded [Microsofts Compression NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Compression) before... glancing at some code I've used DeflateStream in the System.IO.Compression namespace to decompress stuff.

and as you already have something for handling local file I won't mention anything for that.